# Achieve multiple parallel features in Gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit, review

How can multiple parallel features be achieved in Gerrit?
I have several features which need to go in Gerrit for Code Review and until we have been working each developer pushes one feature and waits for it to pass code review if it needs to be fixed we patch it and wait until it passes the Code review (one feature at a time). But now the team that was doing code reviews got pretty small in members, so I have to wait 2 days for a code review. And based on the rules we set up when we started (which don't apply anymore, but I only know this workflow now), each developer can have only on commit at a time for code review in gerrit, I have to wait and not work on anything else until that commit has passed Code Review.
How can I bypass this and work pararelly in Gerrit? For example I have the local branch `dev` and I have the remote gerrit branch `refs/for/dev` now I push a feature that is `commit A`, how do I push another commit, `commit B` in the same branch `refs/for/dev` without it showing up as a dependency in Gerrit?
And what will happen if for example the `commit B` is merged but `commit A` didn't pass code review and needs to be patched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to work the commits in parallel, like this:

1) Create a branch for the first change

```
git fetch
git checkout -b change-1 origin/dev
```

2) Do the first change

```
<edit>
git add .
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```

3) Create a branch for the second change

```
git fetch
git checkout -b change-2 origin/dev
```

4) Do the second change

```
<edit>
git add .
git commit
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```

If you need to create another patchset for one of the changes do the following:

```
git checkout change-NUM
<edit>
git add .
git commit --amend
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev
```

When a change was merged remove its local branch:

```
git branch -D change-NUM
```

Comment: Probably the push in step 2 should be `refs/for/change-1` and the push in step 4 should be `refs/for/change-2`. You can't push different work to the same dest.

Comment: I need to create the branches (`change-1`; `change-2`) locally and push them into the `refs/for/dev`? Or do I need to also create them remotely and push into them, e.g. push the `change-1` into `refs/for/change-1`?

Comment: @mkasberg Gerrit is able to automatically identify commits and associate them to the correct change if you use the Change-Ids. See more info about Change-Ids in the Gerrit documentation: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-changeid.html

Comment: @Mina You don't need to create the branches remotely only locally. In fact, you do not even have to create them locally but it's easy to work (checkout to amend commits) if you have.

Comment: @MarceloÁviladeOliveira You're right, if these commits should all be merged to the `dev` branch after they're reviewed. But if, for example, the goal is to work on feature-1 with multiple iterations of Gerrit review and work on feature-2 with multiple iterations of Gerrit review at the same time, then you need to push to the correct location so Gerrit knows to merge some reviews to `change-1` when the review is complete and others to `change-2` when the review is complete. I think we just interpreted the question slightly differently...

Comment: @mkasberg No, don't worry with multiple iterations of the changes... Gerrit will keep all change-1 patchsets separeted from all change-2 patchsets and, at the end, Gerrit will know how to integrate the last patchset of each change. Don't worry... one change will not interfere with the other.

Comment: My point was simply that pushing to `refs/for/foobar` will merge to a branch named `foobar` when you hit the merge button.

Comment: Ok, now I got you.